# Copy/Paste events for javascript on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, ios, webkit

It appears that oncopy and onpaste do not work with iOS devices that support copy and paste now.  Is there another means to bind to these events in javascript?

Comment: One problem with paste event in iOS is that it fires BEFORE the content actually changes and contains the pasted data. So make sure to put some defer (setInterval) before you check if the content changed or you start working with it!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attached any code with your question, so I can't tell what was the actual issue.

Probably the issue is with your code.

I used the following html code and it is working perfectly. Please check with this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function read()
            {
                var name = document.getElementById('p').value;
                alert('Hi: '+name);
            }

            function copy()
            {
                alert('Copy');
            }

            function paste()
            {
                alert('Paste');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body oncopy='copy();' onpaste='paste();'>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name='m' id='p'/>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='read();'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```